# SVG Adding Padding to other elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having some issues getting an SVG to play well in the layout that I have written.  Here is the example I have for the working table-cell layout that I have been working on.  The first jsfiddle links to the working example.  When I replace the text on the left with an SVG for some reason, the content on the right column gets pushed down.  Any idea why?

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tuzimaster/14toyey2/9/)

[broken example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tuzimaster/r3yxcL52/3/)

Working Example HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="row">
    <div id="left-col">
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available
    </div>
    <div id="right_col">
        <aside><strong>ASIDE</strong></aside>
        <div id="banner1">Banner 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Broken Example HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="row">
    <div id="left-col">
        <div id="divMapContainer" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
            <svg width="400" height="100">
                <rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_col">
        <aside><strong>ASIDE</strong></aside>
        <div id="banner1">Banner 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 1em;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 46em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
    /* 768px */
    #wrapper {
        display: table;
    }
    header {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
    nav,
    #banner2 {
        display: block;
    }
    #row {
        /* the rule below is redundant
   thanks to SelenlT2
*/
        /*display: table-cell;*/
    }
    #left-col,
    #right_col {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    #left-col {
        width: 50%;
    }
    footer {
        display: table-footer-group;
    }
}

#banner1 {
    background-color: #9ed6f9;
    height: 50%;
}

#left-col,
#right_col {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#right_col {
    height: 100%;
}

aside {
    background-color: #fbcdfa;
    height: 50%;
}

#left-col,
aside {
    text-align: left;
    padding: .5em;
}

nav,
header,
#banner1,
#banner2,
footer {
    text-align: center;
}

.note {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because SVG elements are inline by default. You can set the `vertical-align` property on your SVG so that the other elements will align to the top of it. [See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3yxcL52/4/).

```
svg {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```